# VS2010 Report Viewer for empty month totals

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reportviewer

I have a table with sales data and need to generate a report using VS2010 report viewer.  I can do a basic grouping by month, but need a way to insert a record that includes months with no activity.  the input table is:

[image: Input table]

The report should show something like:

```
Month                Sales
Jan                  1303
Feb                  250
Mar                  0
Apr                  500
```

Any recommendations or suggested articles would be greatly appreciated..

Rob

Comment: What error do you get when you try to insert March with 0 sales?

Comment: The system that populates the table, doesn't record any activity.  The example shown is a sample/demo of a larger system, but the concept is that as sales of items are made, they are entered onto the table. The report needs to show totals per month, even if there is no recorded activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate data in VS2010 before using them as `ReportDataSource`.

```
Dim dtTest As New DataTable
dtTest.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Date", GetType(System.DateTime)))
dtTest.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Item", GetType(System.String)))
dtTest.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Value", GetType(System.Double)))

dtTest.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 13), "item1", 1200)
dtTest.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 20), "item1", 103)
dtTest.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2015, 2, 9), "item1", 250)
dtTest.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2015, 4, 2), "item1", 500)
dtTest.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 5), "item2", 100)
dtTest.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 30), "item2", 10)
dtTest.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2015, 2, 3), "item2", 20)
dtTest.Rows.Add(New DateTime(2015, 3, 7), "item2", 50)

'report data source
Dim dtReportDataSource As New DataTable

Dim dcYear As New DataColumn("Year", GetType(System.Int32))
Dim dcMonth As New DataColumn("Month", GetType(System.Double))
Dim dcItem As New DataColumn("Item", GetType(System.String))
Dim dcSum As New DataColumn("Sum", GetType(System.Double))

dtReportDataSource.Columns.Add(dcYear)
dtReportDataSource.Columns.Add(dcMonth)
dtReportDataSource.Columns.Add(dcItem)
dtReportDataSource.Columns.Add(dcSum)

dtReportDataSource.Columns("Sum").DefaultValue = 0
dtReportDataSource.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dcYear, dcMonth, dcItem}

Dim dtStartDate As DateTime = CDate(dtTest.Select("", "Date")(0)("Date"))
Dim dtEndDate As DateTime = CDate(dtTest.Select("", "Date DESC")(0)("Date"))

For i As Integer = 0 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, dtStartDate, dtEndDate)

    Dim intYear As Integer = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, i, dtStartDate).Year
    Dim intMonth As Integer = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, i, dtStartDate).Month

    For Each drTest As DataRow In New DataView(dtTest).ToTable(True, "Item").Rows
        dtReportDataSource.Rows.Add(intYear, intMonth, drTest("Item"))
    Next drTest

Next i

For Each drTest As DataRow In dtTest.Rows

    Dim drReportDataSource As DataRow = dtReportDataSource.Rows.Find(New Object() {CDate(drTest("Date")).Year, CDate(drTest("Date")).Month, drTest("Item")})

    If Not IsNothing(drReportDataSource) Then drReportDataSource("Sum") += drTest("Value")

Next drTest

YouReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("Test", dtReportDataSource))
```